# What is Major Difference between Integration Testing and Behavioral Testing BDD

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, integration-testing, bdd

Over the last few years TDD get very popular and some home another version of testing comes up wit Integration testing and now Behavioral testing BDD is the major focus can some one explain the major difference between BDD and Integration testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's like apples and oranges..

**BDD** is about naming your tests according to the behaviour of the system. So instead of saying `testThisAndThat()` you say `doesThisAndThat()`. If BDD is used as a "methodology" in the team, then every team member (including BAs, QAs) is using the same notation to write the specification and tests. See [this](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/20157/benefits-of-bdd/20220#20220) for more details.

**Integration Testing** has different meanings for different people, most popular usage:

- Testing how your system works with other systems
- Testing multiple layers/parts of the code (multiple units together) aka Component Testing
- Testing your API aka System Testing for Service API

So Integration Testing term is heavily overloaded, check [this](http://qala.io/blog/holes-in-test-terminology.html) out for more details.

Comment: Is it a regular practice to test multiple components of a big system with a BDD approach?

Comment: BDD is just about the name and the structure of tests. You can write any kind of tests on any level with BDD. And it's a pretty common practice on all the levels. As for BDD as methodology that includes BAs - no, it's not common.